# symfony 5.3 connecting Microsoft sql server mssql

Tags: symfony

I intend to connect symfony with sql server.

so far all the researches have not worked,
I would like you to help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

To connect to SQL Server using Symfony, you need to download the PHP pdo_sqlsrv extensions and then all you have to do is set the configuration in your .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlsrv://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:1433/database_name
```